# MOBO turns on when power connected, and black screen

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

So whenever I connect my motherboard to power, the fans and LEDs turn on without me pressing the power switch. In fact, I can't turn it *off* even by holding down the power switch. It even powers on automatically when I disconnect the power switch from the motherboard.

In addition, no signal is outputted to the screen. I have verified that the graphics card works with a different computer.

The motherboard displays the same symptoms when breadboarding it, with or without a working CMOS battery, and a different power supply. Any way to get it back up and functioning?

Comment: This sounds like a power supply problem.

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention, I also tried a separate psu, i'll edit the question now.

Comment: If you have eliminated the power supply as the cause then the only alternative explanation is there is something wrong with the motherboard itself.

Comment: I have had cases before though, were after taking apart everything and putting it back togeather, the mobo started working again

Comment: Well I assume you have tried that.  Otherwise shame on you for not trying it.

Comment: haha, yeah I tried that, but I was wondering if even so, we could figure out what exactly was wrong with the mobo given the specific symptom of turning on when supplied power

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess the motherboard has a short in it, its safe to say, its basically defective.

Comment: Sounds very much as if the circuits connected to the power switch connector are failed in the "button pressed" state, so as soon as the "power good" signal from PSU becomes true, the MB starts -- and since the power switch is "held", it never detects following power button presses.  That "held" power switch is probably also causing the no-output condition; it's preventing the BIOS from initializing the GPU and completing POST.  Unfortunately, on most motherboards I've dealt with, this function is primarily controlled in the highly integrated chipset, not in components someone might replace.

Comment: I've seen a computer power on automatically when plugged in, there's a setting in the BIOS about that.. I have seen the same computer also have various power issues, - two faulty power supplies - and sometimes fans spun slowly, but it turned on sometimes. You could try to look at the screen issue.Try another screen,I know u tried the graphics card in another computer, but still, try a  different graphics card. Maybe there's a weird inexplicable incompatibility of some kind.  If it has other graphic outputs e.g. hdmi try that.The more other things u try that don't work,the more likely its MBRD.